# How to switch CSS stylesheet depending on a header value?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core

I have a implemented multi-tenant themes in Blazor server-side app by getting the header in the `_Host.cshtml`. This was rather easy to do. After getting the tenant from the header, I just did:

```
@{
    Layout = null;

    var css = Model.Tenant.Stylesheet;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(css))
    {
        css = "/css/default.min.css";
    }
}

<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@(css)">
</head>
```

I have an older ASP.NET MVC app (NET7) and was wondering how to do the same? All my styles are in the `_Styles.cshtml`. If I add code similar to the above in this file, would this be enough to enable tenant styling?

Comment: Is _Styles.cshtml your layout page?

Comment: No. I have a separate layout page.

Comment: Then how do you share the styles in_ Styles.cshtml.to other View?  as the partialView of layout page?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Yes. I have `<partial name="_Styles" />` in the layout's `Head` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read your request header directly in you _Style.cshtml

```
@{
    this.Context.Request.Headers.["X-Tenant-Id"]
}
```

You could also try with a Filter  and pass the value with ViewBag/ViewData :

```
public class TanentViewFilter : IActionFilter
    {
       
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
           
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller;
            //you could also read tenant from requestheader
            var tenant=context.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("X-Tenant-Id") ? context.HttpContext.Request.Query["X-Tenant-Id"].ToString():"";
           //modify the logical here
            if (tenant== "sometenant")
            {
                controller.ViewBag.TanentCss = "/css/tenant/yellow.css";
            }
           
        }
    }
```

apply the filter to all controller/action:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(x => x.Filters.Add(typeof(TanentViewFilter)));
```

apply the filter to the specific controller/action through put the attribute on it:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(TanentViewFilter))]
```

in _Styles.cshtml I've tried:

```
@{


    Layout = null;

    var css = "~/css/tenant/default.css";

    if (ViewBag.TanentCss != null)
    {
        css = ViewBag.TanentCss as string;
    }
   

}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="@(css)" />
```

The Result:

[image]